# The relationship between bank conflict and coalesced access in CUDA

Tags: cuda, coalesce, bank-conflict

I try to transfer some data from shared memory to global memory. Some consecutive threads will access one bank (but not the same 32 bits). So there are some bank conflicts. (I use Visual Profiler to check this)
However, those data also be coalesced and then be transfered to global memory. (I use Visual Profiler to check this)
Why are the data wrote into global memory with coalesced way? In my opinion, a streaming multi-processor pops the 32-bit word one by one (based on bank's bandwidth). So the memory transactions can not be coalesced in global memory.
I may make some mistakes here. Please help to find the mistakes out or give me a reasonable explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different things going on here: the read, which incurs a bank conflict, and the write, which may not be coalesced. Since shared memory is much much faster than global, you usually need to worry about the coalesced access first.

Coalescing means that the threads are writing into a small range of memory addresses. For example, if thread 1 writes to address 1 and thread 2 to address 2, this is good. If the write to addresses* 1 and 4, respectively, this is worse. Less importantly, it's optimal if threads write into increasing addresses starting at a multiple of 32, for example addresses 32 and 33. *(I use "address" loosely here, meaning a 4-byte offset).

Bank conflicts occur when multiple threads access shared memory addresses that have the same lower bits (specifically, are equivalent mod 16). If two threads use the same bank, then they will be *serialized*, meaning one will execute after the other, instead of both accessing memory at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry I do not know how to submit codes here. Visual Profiler told me the program has a lot of bank conflicts, but there is no uncoalesced store (All are coalesced store). I would like to know the relationship between banks (bandwidth?) and coalesced access. Will the bandwidth of banks be use for transfering data from shared memory to global memory?

Comment: No, each thread first reads from shared memory, then writes to global memory. So, if all stores are coalesced, there's not too much you need to worry about. Bank conflicts are a problem if they happen when you're doing compute-intensive stuff in shared memory; if it's just the one read before you write to global, it's probably not an issue. Maybe good to get another opinion though.